# rails uniq method vs. uniq_by method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I have the following line in a controller:

```
unique_recipients = conversation.recipients.uniq_by { |r| r.master_profile.email }
```

`conversation` and `recipients` and `master_profile` are active record associations. The line works exactly the way I need it to: I get conversation recipients (each of which has a `master_profile`) that don't have email addresses in common (i.e. I don't send notification emails twice to the same address). Except that every time that line gets run, I see a `DEPRECATED` warning in the tests telling me to use `uniq` instead. So I tried changing that line to the following:

```
unique_recipients = conversation.recipients.uniq { |r| r.master_profile.email }
```

When I do that, the resulting list does contain recipients sharing the same email address on their `master_profile`. What am I missing about the way the `uniq` method works?

Answer (score 1):

Check the source. uniq_by is identical to uniq.

http://apidock.com/rails/Array/uniq_by

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
unique_recipients = conversation.recipients.map{|r| r.master_profile.email}.uniq
```